# Binary Vector Communication

Tags: number-theory

Alice holds an $n$ x $n$ binary matrix $A$, and Bob holds an $n$ x $n$ binary matrix $B$. They want to check whether $A = B$, but they do not want to communicate too much. Here is what they do: Alice tosses a coin $n$ times, and generates a $0-1$ vector $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$. She sends Bob the binary vector $x$, and the binary vector $Ax \mod 2$. Bob computes $Bx$ and rejects if $Ax \ne Bx$. So rejection happens after communicating just $2n + 1$ bits.

How do I show that if $A \ne B$ then they reject with probability $\geqslant 1/2$.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The $i$-th coordinate of $Ax$ and $Bx$ is different if and only if
$A_i x + B_i x = 1 \pmod 2$, which is true if and only if $(A_i + B_i)x=1 \pmod 2.$
We know that $A\neq B$, so there is at least one row $i$ on which $A$ and $B$ differ.
But since $A_i \neq B_i$, then $A_i + B_i$ is a non-zero vector $c$.
Hence $(A x)_i \neq (B x)_i$ if and only if the parity of $x$ at the nonzero positions of $c$
is even.
But $x$ is random, so the parity at the positions $c$, for any nonzero $c$ is odd/even w.p. exactly $1/2$.

Comment: You can use \pmod 2 to get $\pmod 2$.  It puts the mod in the proper font and supplies the parentheses and spacing.  If the modulus is more than one character, it needs to be put in braces.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the situation where just one entry of the matrices differs.  The products will differ if that entry is multiplied by a $1$ and not if it is multiplied by $0$, so they will disagree $\frac 12$ of the time.  Then argue that having more disagreements in the same row can't cancel this out.  Each row is independent.